# Routing outbound SMTP with IPTables

Tags: iptables, smtp

I am trying to transparently filter outbound SPAM from one of my hosting boxes. I have set up an external mail server that filters SPAM and now I am looking for a way to route all outbound SMTP traffic from the hosting server to the Mail Scanner with IPTables.

Eg. -- Outbound SMTP (1.1.1.1 port 25) --> MailScanner (6.6.6.6 port 2500)

So far my closest attempt has lead me to LAND attacks showing on our CISCO firewalls.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp -j SNAT --dport 2500 --to-source 6.6.6.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may consider where the outbound trafic are going to, it go from 1.1.1.1 port 25 to ? you have to mach this trafic -and only this- and send it to 6.6.6.6

May be --sport 25 are enought.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the *destination* of the traffic, you need DNAT, not SNAT. You also need to match the specific packets you want to DNAT (i.e. destined for port 25).

`iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --dport 25 --jump DNAT --to-destination 6.6.6.6:2500`

Comment: I think this is very close. However I get the following.

ip_tables: DNAT target: used from hooks POSTROUTING, but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT

Comment: For the locally generated traffic (which I believe is a case here) DNAT is performed in OUTPUT chain.